# Update DataTable after cell edit not working in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

I have a datatable includes some cell for edit, and these cells are disabled in specific conditions and after an other cell edition will be enabled.
My problem is after the edit, the new data stored in the database but the datatable not updated directly, it will be updated after reloading the page.

All what I want is how can I make the hole datatable updated after the edit or making the page reloaded

and here is my code:

```
<h:form id="process">
        <p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" update=":process:ListC" />
    <p:dataTable id="ListC"
        value="#{recruitmentProcessMB.candidateListInProcess}"          
        var="candid" rowKey="#{candid.idCandidate}"
        style="border:0px; " paginator="true"
        paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="3,5,10" paginatorPosition="top"
        rows="10" editable="true" editMode="cell">
        <f:facet name="footer" >
            <h:outputLabel value="Valider processus pour le Manager:" style="display: inline-block;"/>

            <h:selectOneMenu id="managersInProcess" style="display: inline-block;"
                             value="#{recruitmentProcessMB.selectedManagerInProcess}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner..." itemValue="#{null}"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{recruitmentProcessMB.managersInProcess}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />

            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-seek-next" 
                value="Valider le processus"
                ajax="true"
                style="display: inline-block;"
                disabled="false"></p:commandButton>

        </f:facet>

         <p:ajax  event="cellEdit" 
                    update=":process:ListC"
                    immediate="true"
                    listener="#{recruitmentProcessMB.onCellEdit}"
                    process="@this" 
                    oncomplete="onCellEdit()"

                 />

        <p:column headerText="Prenom">
            <h:outputText value="#{candid.firstNameCandidate}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Nom">
            <h:outputText value="#{candid.nameCandidate}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Specialité">
            <h:outputText value="#{candid.specialityCandidate}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Niveau d'etude">
            <h:outputText value="#{candid.levelStudyCandidate}" />
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="CV" style="text-align: center ;width:30px;">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s"
                ajax="false"
                actionListener="#{recruitmentProcessMB.downloadAction(candid.cvCandidate,candidate.nameCandidate,candidate.firstNameCandidate)}">

                <p:fileDownload
                    value="#{recruitmentProcessMB.downloadContentProperty}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Manager" style="position:center;">
            <h:outputText
                value="#{candid.employee.firstNameEmployee} #{candid.employee.nameEmployee}" />

        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Date d'entretien">
            <p:cellEditor id="c1">
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{candid.interviewDateCandidate}">
                        <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short"
                            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="Europe/Paris" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input" >
                    <p:calendar id="dateInterview"
                        value="#{candid.interviewDateCandidate}"
                        navigator="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" immediate="true" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>

        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Validation Par Manager " >
            <p:cellEditor id="c2">
                <f:facet name="output" >
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{candid.decisionOfManager}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"  >
                         <h:selectOneMenu id="manegerDecision" style="display: inline-block;"
                                    value="#{candid.decisionOfManager}"
                                    disabled="#{candid.currentTask!='InterviewAndValidationByManager'}" 
                                    immediate="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner..." />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Accepté" itemValue="Accepté"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Refusé" itemValue="Refusé"/>

                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>

        </p:column>

        <p:column  headerText="Validation Par RH " >
        <p:cellEditor id="c3" >
            <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText
                value="#{candid.decisionOfRh}" />
                </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                 <h:selectOneMenu id="rhDecision" style="display: inline-block;"
                            value="#{candid.decisionOfRh}"
                            disabled="#{candid.currentTask!='InterviewAndValidationByRH'}" 
                            immediate="true">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner..." />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Accepté" itemValue="Accepté"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Refusé" itemValue="Refusé"/>

            </h:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>

        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: What is `oncelledit`? Is there anything of interest in your javascript console

Comment: I have not used a p:cellEditor before but one of the way is just use a ajax after you take the new data (inside your components like selectOneMenu etc.) and update your p:datatable from the ajax inside the same table.This will reload your tabledata with new value. There may be better options also!.